# How to mount 192.168.0.3:/dev/sda to local:/mnt/sda for cryptsetup luksOpen /mnt/sda?

Tags: mount, devices, remote, cryptsetup

as mentioned above, I have a cryptsetup full disk encrypted device on /dev/sda at 192.168.0.3. And I am at 192.168.0.2.

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen user@192.168.0.3:/dev/sda encHDD
$ sudo mount /dev/mapper/encHDD /mnt/encHDD
$ ls -lha /mnt/encHDD
```

How can I make this command possible?

Answer (score 0):

Network Block Device will allow remote access to the block device.

If you trust the remote server you could mount it on the server and use a network filing system.

Note that in any case the server will know which parts of the disk are accessed and this may be sensitive information. If that is a problem copy the entire disk (or part of).

Comment: In case network speed is high but CPU of the server is slow with full-encryption-disk mounted on it, crypt-mounting server:/dev/sda through network with fast CPU on the client's side might be a better choice?